# Convert a complex layered JSON to CSV

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to parse through JSON code and write the results into a csv file. The "name" values are supposed to be the column headers and the 'value' values are what need to be stored.This is my code. the CSV file writer does not separate the strings with commas: eventIdlistingsvenueperformer and when I try to  do something like: header = col['name']+',' I get: eventId","listings","venue","performer And it isn't read as a csv file so...My questions are: am I going about this right? and how could I separate the strings by commas?

```
"results": [
    {
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "eventId",
          "value": "XXXX",
          "defaultHidden": false
        },
        {
          "name": "listings",
          "value": "8",
          "defaultHidden": false
        },
        {
          "name": "venue",
          "value": "Nationwide Arena",
          "defaultHidden": false
        }]
```

this is my code:

```
json_decode=json.loads(data)
report_result = json_decode['results']
with open('testReport2.csv','w') as result_data:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(result_data,delimiter=',')
    count = 0
    for res in report_result:
        deeper = res['columns']
        for col in deeper:
            if count == 0:
                 header = col['name']
                 csvwriter.writerow([header,])
        count += 1

    for written in report_result:
        deeper =res['columns']
        for col in deeper:
            csvwriter.writerow([trouble,])
    result_data.close()
```

Comment: What do you want to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code:

```
json_decode=json.loads(data)
report_result = json_decode['results']
new_dict = {}
for result in report_result:
    columns = result["columns"]
    for value in columns:
        new_dict[value['name']] = value['value']

with open('testReport2.csv','w') as result_data:
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(result_data,delimiter=',',fieldnames=new_dict.keys())
    csvwriter.writeheader()
    csvwriter.writerow(new_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I ran this code and it worked beautifully. My last obstacle is that there are multiple sections inside Columns( 'columns':{{dataset1},{dataset2}....}) so how can I get it to run for all the items inside columns. calling header once but checking the values inside all the data sets.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
json_decode=json.loads(data)
report_result = json_decode['results']
with open('testReport2.csv','w') as result_data:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(result_data,delimiter=',')
    header = list(report_result[0]['columns'][0].keys())
    csvwriter.writerow(header)

    for written in report_result:
        for row in written['columns']:
            deeper =row.values()
            csvwriter.writerow(deeper)
    result_data.close()
```